# Need to apply for CCATS if using simple XOR cipher?

Tags: iphone, encryption, app-store-connect

iTunesConnect states that developers need to get a CCATS Classification if using encryption in the app. My app uses a simple XOR obfuscation cipher when transferring data over HTTP. Does this still fall under that requirement? If not, then what type of encryption need to be CCATS classified?

Answer (score 2):

**I am not qualified to offer legal advice.**

**Your probably need to consult with a lawyer to get a answer, as this is a legal matter.**

I read the regulations [here](http://law.justia.com/cfr/title15/15cfr740_main_02.html). *My opinion* is that if it is a publically available symetric algorithm, which XOR is, as long as the key length is 64-bit or less, then you don't need a license. So, if your key length is 64-bits or less, you do not fall under that requirement.

Again *this is just my opinion*, but from reading Title 15.B.VII.C.742.15, encryption that needs to be CCATS classified is:

- symetric encryption that uses key lengths longer than 64-bits
- proprietary (non-public) encryption with key lengths longer than 56-bits
- asymetric key exchange algorithms with key lengths greater than 512-bits
- elliptic curve algotihms with key lengths greater than 112-bits